# Need assistance with my deprecated FirebaseInstanceId code

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase, push-notification

The FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated and need to fix the code. Here below I'll post the errors and the code after that. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
 ^

 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(senderId, "*");
 ^

Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
^

String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");
               ^
```

Here below you'll see the code:

```
 private Task<Void> deleteToken(Map<String, Object> arguments) {
return Tasks.call(
    cachedThreadPool,
    () -> {
      String senderId =
          arguments.get("senderId") != null
              ? (String) arguments.get("senderId")
              : Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
      FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteToken(senderId, "*");
      return null;
    });


}


private Task<Map<String, Object>> getToken(Map<String, Object> arguments) {
return Tasks.call(
    cachedThreadPool,
    () -> {
      String senderId =
          arguments.get("senderId") != null
              ? (String) arguments.get("senderId")
              : Metadata.getDefaultSenderId(FirebaseApp.getInstance());
      String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken(senderId, "*");
      return new HashMap<String, Object>() {
        {
          put("token", token);
        }
      };
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0):

> FirebaseInstanceId is deprecated but now you can use FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token

e.g.

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        if(result != null){
            firebaseToken = result
            // do what ever you want to do with Firebase token
        }
}
```